# Linux env -i oddity

Tags: linux, shell, environment

This works as expected:

```
[dgorur@ted ~]$ env -i env
[dgorur@ted ~]$
```

As does this:

```
[dgorur@ted ~]$ env -i which date
which: no date in ((null))
```

But look at this:

```
[dgorur@ted ~]$ env -i  date
Fri Aug 28 22:27:15 PDT 2015
```

Interesting. And how about this:

```
[dgorur@ted ~]$ env -i  whereis date
date: /bin/date /opt/rocks/bin/date /usr/share/man/man1p/date.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/date.1.gz
```

What's going on? Does an empty environment not mean what one would think it does, or are some commands special? Oh, and `ls` works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "empty environment" isn't quite so.

From [the source code](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/env.c) for `env`, one sees that it runs:

```
execvp (argv[optind], &argv[optind]);
```

If one, in turn, reads `man execvp`, one finds that it will create its own PATH if you don't supply one:

> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified filename does not  contain  a  slash
>       (/)  character.  The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the PATH environment variable.  **If this variable isn't defined, the path
>       list defaults to the current directory  followed  by  the  list  of  directories  returned  by  confstr(_CS_PATH).   (This  confstr(3)  call  typically  returns  the  value
>              "/bin:/usr/bin".)** [emphasis added.]

Consequently, programs that are in that default PATH work fine:

```
$ env -i env
$ env -i which date
/bin/date
$ env -i  date
Fri Aug 28 23:12:21 PDT 2015
```

(My `env -i which date` behaves differently from yours, likely due to the implementation of `which`.)

In my tests, the default PATH includes the current directory. Anything command not in the system's default PATH, however, such as commands that you may have in `~/bin`, will fail under `env -i`.